# C#: What should the regular expression be for this?

Tags: c#, regex, text

I know that there are many [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN1) parser out there but they cost quite a lot and as such, I am trying to write my own.

I am kind of new to Regular Expression so in order to extract the text for the placeholders A, B, C and D, what should the Regular Expression be in C#?

```
A ::= B
{
    C1 D1,
    C2 D2,
    C3 D3
}
```

where A, C and D can be any valid word which consists of any combination of the following

- `A-Z`
- `a-z`
- `0-9`
- `_`

And B can be any ASN.1 types such as "SEQUENCE", "SEQUENCE OF", "CHOICE", "UTF8String", etc. A full list can be found in "Universal Class Tags" table at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_encoding_rules).

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally don't like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Have you looked at any open source implementations, such as asn1c?

Comment: Are you going to use this regex as part of a lexer for a parser, or are you actually trying to parse it with regular expressions?

Comment: @Matthew: Is there any open source implementations for converting from ASN.1 into C# code?

Comment: @Anon: I am using the regex to break up the above text structure into the respective parts for A, B, C and D and then I am going to make use of the text found in those placeholders in order to generate C# code.

Comment: I wonder what this fascination is with "if it's not in the language I know, it's completely useless to me".

Comment: Are there always exactly three entries (C1/D1-C3/D3)? If so, you *could* do it with a regex. If not, especially if there is no upper bound for the number of entries, it's not possible with a single regex (if you want to capture each value by itself). Alan Moore is still right - even if you could do it, it's probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to match that whole construct with one regex?  That's a bad idea.  Regexes can be useful as a *component* of a parser, but it's best to keep their role to a minimum.  Don't try to match large chunks of text, especially recursive or looping structures.  C# regexes are powerful enough to handle such things in many cases, but not all--and that's way beyond beginner level anyway.

I suggest you try it without using regexes at all.  Otherwise you'll constantly be distracting yourself, wondering how the regex technique you haven't learned yet would make the current task easier, or solve the problem more elegantly (if you'll pardon my language).  Concentrate on writing solid, readable, *maintainable* code--that being another weakness of regexes.